# Visual Studio Extension to attach debugger to remote process running in .NET Core on Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio, .net-core, vsix

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to develop a .NET Core 3 application which runs on embedded Linux. I am able to build the code in Visual Studio 2019. If I copy the binaries manually to the Linux machine and then start the application running there then I am able to attach the Visual Studio debugger to the remote process over SSH in Linux and debug the application. This does work, but it's tedious to deploy it, start it and attach the debugger manually for each debug session. I do have a script in Visual Studio Code which works, but I want to use Visual Studio Professional.

I'm trying to write a Visual Studio Extension so that I can press a key in Visual Studio to have the application built, deployed, started and then connected to the debugger. I would then share the extension with my team. It's very nearly working, except for attaching the debugger.

In the extension I am able to list the processes running in the Linux machine and select my application using this code:

```
EnvDTE100.Debugger5 debugger = (EnvDTE100.Debugger5)dte.Debugger;
EnvDTE80.Transport transport = debugger.Transports.Item("SSH");
EnvDTE80.Engine engine = transport.Engines.Item("Managed (.NET Core for Unix)");
EnvDTE80.Process2 process = (EnvDTE80.Process2)debugger.GetProcesses(transport, "192.168.11.1").Item("app");
process.Attach2(debugger);
```

There are two problems:

1. The call to GetProcesses() opens a dialog where I need to enter the Linux username and press enter, how can I specify the username in code to avoid the dialog appearing?
2. Even though the selected process looks like the right one (process.ProcessID matches what I see in Linux if I run the ps command), I get an exception when I call Attach2(). The exception message is "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8971001E"

I feel like I'm really close to getting this to work, any suggestions for how to finish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to add the user Name, but not the Password:

In `GetProcess()`, set `transportQualifier` to `$"{userName}@{hostName}"`.

The 1st time the Window will still Pop up and ask for the Password.
But after that VisualStudio has stored the connection including the password.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, that worked! Because I have a saved SSH key on my PC I wasn't even asked for a password the first time.

Answer (score 3):

I also solved the second problem by changing the parameter passed to Attach2() from debugger to engine, as shown below:

```
EnvDTE100.Debugger5 debugger = (EnvDTE100.Debugger5)dte.Debugger;
EnvDTE80.Transport transport = debugger.Transports.Item("SSH");
EnvDTE80.Engine engine = transport.Engines.Item("Managed (.NET Core for Unix)");
EnvDTE80.Process2 process = (EnvDTE80.Process2)debugger.GetProcesses(transport, "root@192.168.11.1").Item("app");
process.Attach2(engine);
```

Comment: could you publish your VS extension please or tell if I can use it also ? Thanks